# Python: Selecting repeated elements (list in a list) and put it in an array?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, append, repeat

How to make from this:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

to this?

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

I tried this but it only works with 2 repeated elements. I want it to work for any number of repeated elements.

```
finalRes = []

for i in range(len(resList)-1):
    if resList[i] == resList[i+1]:
        finalRes.append(resList[i])

finalRes --> [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Do you want only the unique elements accross the whole array or only the consecutives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]

result = [key for key, _ in groupby(lst)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find the unique elements in the array.

Use:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
unique_arr = np.unique(arr, axis=0)
print(unique_arr)
```

This prints:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]]
```